# Separation of variable: $f(x)=g(y)$ for all $x,y$ implies $f(x)=g(y)=$ constant, and the constant being eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Question 1: $f(x)=g(y)$ for all $x,y$ implies $f(x)=g(y)=$ constant. This is basically what separation of variables is. But it's still hard for me to accept it. Can anyone tells deeper reason why this is true?

Question 2: $Lf=\lambda f$ for all $f\implies$ $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue. But it looks like it's talking about eigenvalue without specifying eigenvector (eigenfunction) that it is associated with. I just feel it's uncomfortable to claim $\lambda$ to be an eigenvalue without specifying the eigenvector (eigenfunction) that it corresponds to.

Comment: 1.  If, say, $f(a)\neq f(b)$ then we couldn't have both of them equal to $g(c)$. 2. (note: you have misdefined eigenvalue) Eigenvectors are not uniquely defined.  Any scalar multiple of an eigenvector is again an eigenvector and there might be two or more linearly independent eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue.  Accordingly, it is sometimes useful to speak of the eigenvalue without specifying an eigenvector for it.

Comment: Please don't post two distinct questions within the same one.

Comment: @lulu do you mean if $Ax=\lambda x$ for some $x\ne0$ then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue? But at this point we don't really know such $x$ would exist?

Comment: Yes, that is the definition of eigenvalue.  Saying that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue implies that there exists such an $x$ (non-unique, as I mentioned).

Comment: But why is it an eigenvalue in the first place? I don't see the reason why the definition that comes from eigenvector and this definition is consistent?

Comment: Not following at all.  You told us that $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue.  That means that there is an eigenvector associated with it (or several eigenvectors).  Not every number is an eigenvalue for a given operator, clearly.

Comment: No you're not getting me. I'm not used to that definition actually. Suppose I didn't say it. The definition I used to is the wikipedia definition (comes form eigenvector). If $Av=\lambda v$ then $\lambda$ is eigenvalue associated with eigenvector $v$. How to get to the eigenvector-free definition?

Comment: The definition is "$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for the linear operator $L$ iff there exists a non-zero vector $\vec v$ such that $L\vec v = \lambda \vec v$".  Thus, $1$ is an eigenvalue for the identity operator, for example.  There are some useful theorems.  For example, for finite dimensional vector spaces, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $L$ iff $\det (L-\lambda \mathbb 1)=0$ where $\mathbb 1$ denotes the identity matrix.  Is that what you are interested in?

Comment: Yes. Can you show your definition leads to the eigenvector-free definition. i.e. If $Ax=\lambda x$ for some $x\ne 0$ then $\lambda$ is actually an eigenvalue.

Comment: Well, that determinant is $0$ iff $L$ has a non-trivial kernel.  Any non-zero vector in that kernel is, by definition, an eigenvector attached to $\lambda$.  You should read about this in a text on linear algebra.

Answer (score 2):

1. Assume $f(x)=g(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Fix $x_{0},y_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$. Then you have $$f(x)=g(y_{0})={\rm const.}\\g(y)=f(x_{0})={\rm const.}$$ and those constants are equal since also $f(x_{0})=g(y_{0})$.
2. Your second statement seems strange to me. It means that the operator $\hat{L}$ is just $\lambda\hat{I}$ where $\hat{I}$ is the identity operator. Then of course $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: 1. Why are the constant equal? If I have $f(x_1)=g(y_1)\ne f(x_2)=g(y_2)$ what will happen?

Comment: @monotonic You can't have such a case. That's exactly what I've shown: $f$ is the constant $g(y_{0})$, $g$ is the constant $f(x_{0})$ and $f(x_{0})=g(y_{0})\equiv c$ by your assumption.